# Mobiscroll sluggish solution?

Tags: jquery, cordova, mobiscroll

I´m testing out [Mobiscroll](http://mobiscroll.com/) on my phone with JQuery/PhoneGap and it is really sluggish to respond to my interactions.

Have anyone else experienced this? Is there a way to solve it?

```
Versions:
Phone: Xperia X10 (Android 2.3)
Mobiscroll: 2.0.3
JQuery (mobile): 1.2.0
Jquery: 1.8.2
PhoneGap: 2.1.0
```